# MeshLab - Smooth Two Connected Meshes

Tags: smoothing, meshlab

I generated two connected meshes from a software that processes CT Scans (3D Slicer). By connected I mean that they have common points, edges and/or triangles. The software has a neat feature where you can ask it to smooth and decimate the meshes while keeping the connection.

However, the mesh manipulation tools of MeshLab are very good and I would like to use them instead. Is there a way of having this behavior (smoothing while maintaining the connection) in MeshLab? Attached is an example with a very simple mesh.

Separate Meshes:

[image: Left Mesh]
[image: Right Mesh]

Connected Meshes:

[image: Connected Mesh]

Bonus question: Is there a way of exporting the intersecting nodes of the two meshes (before or after the smoothing)?